# Does an anonymous inner class always capture a reference to "this" (outer) object when accessing its primitives etc.?

Tags: java, instance-variables, anonymous-inner-class

If I have

[EDIT: added the type definition for "Inner"]

```
interface Inner{
    public void execute();
}

class Outer{
    int outerInt;
    public void hello(){
        Inner inner = new Inner(){
            public void execute(){
                outerInt=5;
            }
        }

        //later
        inner.execute();
    }
}
```

will the call to `inner.execute()` set the `outerInt` variable of *that particular* `Outer` object to `5`, wherever it is called from, and for as long as that `Inner` object exists? Or will it just change a copy of the `outerInt` variable and not affect the original `Outer` object?

Comment: I think you meant `Outer inner = new Outer()`.

Comment: @toto2 No, he didn't. Although `Inner` is not shown.

Comment: @Bohemian `Inner` is a subclass of `Outer`, so it needlessly adds complexity to this example to make an anonymous subclass of `Inner`.  See my answer where I skipped `Inner`.

Comment: @toto2 Where do you get the idea that `Inner` is a subclass of `Outer`?

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant it exactly as written. Inner has nothing to do with outer, it's just a completely independent type. I have added to the code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your newly clarified question (from the comment to my other answer):

**Yes**.
All inner and local classes will have a reference to their parent's `this`, even if they never use it.
[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/hjmbu).

Answer (score 6):

This will capture and modify the outer `this`.

See the [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#253034)

Comment: That is, that inner this isn't this outer this.

Comment: @toto2: No.  Using a field from the outer class captures the _outer_ `this`.

Comment: Yep, sorry.  I thought somehow that `Inner` was a subclass of `Outer`.

Comment: @SLaks You say using a field from the outer class captures the outer `this` (like in my question). But I wonder if it holds a reference to the outer `this` automatically, regardless of whether or not you use a field or call a method from it, as might be suggested by your excellent link?

Comment: @Navigateur: That's a good question; I don't know.  I would assume yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily true.  You didn't show is the class declaration for Inner.  If Inner has a field called outerInt, then that one will be modified.  Otherwise Outer's outerInt will.  If you run:

```
public class Outer {

    int outerInt = 0;

    public void hello() {
        Inner inner = new Inner() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                outerInt = 5;
            }
        };

        // later
        inner.execute();
        System.out.println(outerInt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer o = new Outer();
        o.hello();
    }
}

class Inner {
    int outerInt;

    public void execute() {

    }
}
```

You will get 0, not 5.

But by commenting out outerInt in Inner, then you get 5

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to show that the given `Inner` instance doesn't have an int variable called `outerInt`. Will the `Inner` object still hold a reference to the outer `this` regardless of whether or not the outer's variable is referred to?

Comment: When you say outerInt from within the anonymous class, it first checks for an outerInt in that class and in each of its super classes.  Then if none is found, it checks for one in Outer and then each of it's super classes and then if Outer is contained in a class it checks that one and so on so forth.  If none is found then you should get a compile-time error.  Java never makes implicit copies of Objects.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now.  Either for anonymous inner classes or just regular inner classes the answer is the same.  If you declare one class inside another without using the static keyword, then you can imagine that instance in which the class is declared is part of the class definition.  If you explicitly name your inner class (say class MyInner extends Inner {...), you cannot instantiate it with new Outer.MyInner because it doesn't know which instance to associate MyInner with (There will be a compile-error to that effect).  You can say o = new Outer().  And then o.new MyInner().

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. But if you have a need to use outer class's instance,  e.g. passing to some method, you have to say Outer.this.